# How can I intrepret this SQL Server ERROR log

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, service

I've spent dozens of hours trying to figure out why I can't connect to my db through the Windows Service I'm writing and am running under `LocalSystem`. A snapshot of the error of is

```
2016-12-07 23:00:39.98 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'thelion'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2016-12-07 23:00:39.99 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2016-12-07 23:00:39.99 Logon       Login failed for user 'thelion'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'LrcPageTask'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2016-12-07 23:04:10.72 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'thelion'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2016-12-07 23:04:10.73 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2016-12-07 23:04:10.73 Logon       Login failed for user 'thelion'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'LrcPageTask'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2016-12-07 23:04:20.75 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'thelion'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2016-12-07 23:04:20.75 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2016-12-07 23:04:20.75 Logon       Login failed for user 'thelion'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'LrcPageTask'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

after calling my `OnStart` method

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ServiceName + " started");
        //PageLoadTimer.Enabled = true;
        try
        {
            repo.Add(new PageDocument()
            {
                Html = "<p>Test</p>",
                PageType = 0,
                DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
                DateProcessed = null
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Problem added a page document: {0}", e.Message));
        }
    }
```

which calls the `Add` method

```
public class PageDocumentRepository : PageCRUD
{
    public void Add(PageDocument pd)
    {
        using(var context = GetPageTaskContext())
        {
            context.PageDocuments.Add(pd);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

where `GetPageTaskContext` is like

```
public abstract class PageCRUD
{
    public LrcPageTaskEntities GetPageTaskContext()
    { 
        return new LrcPageTaskEntities();
    }
}
```

and where `LrcPageTaskEntities` is like

```
public partial class LrcPageTaskEntities : DbContext
{
    public LrcPageTaskEntities()
        : base("name=LrcPageTaskEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<PageDocument> PageDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

and my connection string is like

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="LrcPageTaskEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.LrcPageTask.csdl|res://*/Models.LrcPageTask.ssdl|res://*/Models.LrcPageTask.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-300NQR3\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LrcPageTask;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
    <add name="LrcPageTaskEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.LrcPageTask.csdl|res://*/Models.LrcPageTask.ssdl|res://*/Models.LrcPageTask.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-300NQR3\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LrcPageTask;integrated security=false;user id=thelion;password=trump4america;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web and SQL Server Express 2016.

Any help in solving the mystery?

EDIT: For some additional visibility, here is the login I'm trying to use:

[image]

It doesn't work if I try to log in under `LocalSystem` with `Intregated Security=True` and no `User Id` / `Password` specified (hence the reason I commented out that connection string). If I try that, I get a stream of login errors

```
2016-12-07 23:17:27.95 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'NT SERVICE\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2016-12-07 23:20:37.15 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-300NQR3$'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2016-12-07 23:20:37.16 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2016-12-07 23:20:37.16 Logon       Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-300NQR3$'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'LrcPageTask'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2016-12-07 23:20:47.20 Logon       Login succeeded for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-300NQR3$'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
2016-12-07 23:20:47.20 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
2016-12-07 23:20:47.20 Logon       Login failed for user 'WORKGROUP\DESKTOP-300NQR3$'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'LrcPageTask'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Answer (score 0):

State 38 means `'Login valid but database unavailable (or login not permissioned)'`

If you want to read more about each State in the error log read this blog [`Troubleshooting Error 18456`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456) by *Aaron Bertrand* .

Make sure that the databaes exists and login has a user with appropriate permissions to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Below troubleshooting steps are taken from :[Troubleshoot Connectivity/Login failures (18456 State x) with SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsakthi/2011/02/06/troubleshoot-connectivitylogin-failures-18456-state-x-with-sql-server/)

Few troubleshooting steps relevant to you from the link:

**1.Default Trace:**
You can use  below query to query the default trace

```
DECLARE @trcpath nvarchar(256)

SELECT  @trcpath=
CAST(value as nvarchar(256)) 
FROM  fn_trace_getinfo(default)  WHERE  property = 2

---Change “default” to 1 if you want to read
 information only from current trace file
  SELECT  * FROM fn_trace_gettable (@trcpath,default )
 WHERE  EventClass= 20
 ORDER BY starttime DESC
```

Output will be some thing like below..

> Login failed for user ‘del’. Reason: Failed to open the database specified in the login properties. [CLIENT: ]
>   Login failed for user ‘sa’. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: ]

**2.Ring Buffer and Extended events :**
You can also use ringbuffer DMV along with [Err.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985) to troubleshoot and get reason for Failures..

running below DMV ,gives you some error codes ..

```
SELECT dateadd (ms, (a.[Record Time] - sys.ms_ticks), GETDATE()) as [Notification_Time], a.* FROM 
(SELECT 
x.value('(//Record/@id)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Record_ID], 
x.value('(//Record/Error/ErrorCode)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS [ErrorCode], 
x.value('(//Record/Error/APIName)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS [APIName], 
x.value('(//Record/Error/CallingAPIName)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS [CallingAPIName], 
x.value('(//Record/Error/SPID)[1]', 'int') AS [SPID], 
x.value('(//Record/@time)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Record Time] 
FROM (SELECT CAST (record as xml) FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers 
WHERE ring_buffer_type = 'RING_BUFFER_SECURITY_ERROR') AS R(x)) a 
CROSS JOIN sys.dm_os_sys_info sys 
ORDER BY a.[Record_ID] DESC
```

If it gives for example,say *0x8C2*   ,you can use Err.exe to get error message like below..

```
Err.exe 0x8C2
```

Gives

```
# for hex 0x8c2 / decimal 2242 :
  NERR_PasswordExpired                                          lmerr.h
```

Then you can use NETHELP MSG in command prompt and get more details like..

```
NET HELPMSG 2242
```

Gives

> The password of this user has expired
>
> EXPLANATION
>
> Your password has expired. You will not be able to perform any network tasks until you change your password.
>
> ACTION
>
> To change your password, press Ctrl+Alt+Del and then select Change Password.

**References:**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsakthi/2011/02/06/troubleshoot-connectivitylogin-failures-18456-state-x-with-sql-server/